# How Do I uninstall antigen package manager for zsh from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: zsh

I installed antigen using

```
curl -L git.io/antigen > antigen.zsh
```

this command as per the instructions on the antigen repo and now i wish to completely uninstall from my home directory/system.What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you did that, it should have created an `antigen.zsh` file at the location that you ran that command. You can just delete it with `rm antigen.zsh`.